# Realize as homology a given polynomial ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I am wondering if one can **realize a polynomial ring as the homology of some chain complex** in the same sense that the homology groups of a space with a cell complex structure is the homology of its chain complex. There are trivial solutions for this with a complex with only 0-chains, but I ask for something like a free resolution that is not exact. I hope there is a canonical thing for this, maybe something related to the dimension for algebraic varieties.

The easiest example to apply this, in my case, would be the Tjurina algebra of an isolated hypersurface singularity $(H,x)\subset (\mathbb{C}^{n+1},x)$:
$$T(f)=\frac{\mathcal{O}_{n+1}}{(f)+J(f)},$$
where $H=V(f)$ and $J(f)$ is the ideal generated by the partial derivatives of $f$.

**Motivation:**

There is a spectral sequence that has in the first page some chain complex of some objects $V_i$. In the second you find some easy to compute homologies of some easy objects, $H_*(V_i)$, which is what people use in practice. The spectral sequence is used to calculate the homology of something, say some $H_*(X)$ of $X$. This is very hard to do in general, hence the importance of the spectral sequence.

In turn, there is an associated algebraic object $A(X)$ to $X$ (and to every $V_i$ an associated $A(V_i)$). It seems that if you use the algebraic objects $A(V_i)$ instead of $H_*(V_i)$ in the **SECOND** page of a spectral sequence similar to the previous one (if it exists?) you would also compute $A(X)$. The problem is that the proof that works for homologies $H_*(X)$ uses that you have a double complex where you find the chain complexes of the $V_i$ (this is the FIRST page of the spectral sequence). I don't have such chain complexes for the algebraic setting, so I cannot prove that the spectral sequence converges to what I want.

(Maybe it is not the first and the second page, but the $0$-th and the first, that is not important).

Comment: A spectral sequence computing a given ring would be appreciated too, in fact this is my main goal in some sense.

Comment: If you pick any graded vector space and turn in into a complexwith zero differential, you realize it as the homology of a complex.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez this is what I meant by "only zero-chains" in the question (to say a degree), but I appreciate the comment.

Comment: Being more specific about what you want would help, then; right now the burdens of both question and answer are on the reader.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojević I have added my motivation. I tried to simplify it as much as I could.

Comment: I have read a few times your question and I still have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

Comment: "I ask for something like a free resolution that is not exact" - this sentence seem to manifestly contradict itself.

Comment: Could it possibly be that what you want are Tate-Józefiak resolutions, see, e.g. https://eudml.org/doc/214408 (though there is an enormous body of literature on the topic)?

Comment: Where does the ring structure come from? Is the chain complex supposed to be DGA?

Comment: @user43326 The algebraic objects for the simpler objects, $A(V_i)$, are the Tjurina algebras of some ICIS (isolated complete intersection singularities). This is just the ring of polynomial quotient some ideal. The target of this spectral sequence, the $A(X)$, would be something similar, but it is a module with mixed structure and it is a bit weird to explain in a comment.

The chain complex of $X$ comes from its simplicial structure of $X$, as topological space.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Given a candidate to have a spectral sequence that converges to a weird module, how do I prove that it does in fact, converge, if I know the second page of the sequence and its entries (some rings)?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko This seems very related to what I want, if not precisely it. I will take a closer look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems related to the Steenrod problem (see below). As far as I know it's still open. Here are a couple of references; maybe the Anderson-Grodal one is closer to what you're looking for. N.B. I think there are some other problems known as Steenrod's problem so you may have to sift through what you get from Google or Mathscinet.

Smith, Justin R. Topological realizations of chain complexes. I. The general theory.
Topology Appl. 22 (1986), no. 3, 301–313.

Andersen, Kasper K. S.; Grodal, Jesper The Steenrod problem of realizing polynomial cohomology rings. J. Topol. 1 (2008), no. 4, 747–760.

Smith's paper is concerned with the non-simply connected case; his abstract gives some background:

Abstract: This paper studies the following question: Given a group $\pi$, and a projective $\pi$-chain complex $C$, does there exist a topological space with a fundamental group $\pi$ and with the property that the chain-complex of its universal cover is chain-homotopy equivalent to $C$? This is generalization of the Steenrod Problem. In the Steenrod Problem (proposed by Steenrod in 1960) the chain complex was a projective resolution of a
$\pi$-module. The present paper develops an obstruction theory for the existence of topological realizations of a chain-complex, algebraically classifies these realizations (if the obstructions vanish), and proves that rational chain-complexes are always stably realizable.